# Copied Database and Source Code of Rails APP into another server, New URL redirecting to old website URL when run from browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have moved the source code and  database of a rails APP from one server to another. When we try to run the site from the new server using IP address, it is redirecting and loading the old website url. Can anybody please advise what is the cause for it. How do i resolve the issue so that i can load the website using the IP?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the files `development.rb` and `production.rb` - you might need to update the default urls there.

As well default_url_options or IP-addresses might be white/black-listed in `application.rb`